# How sure is cin.clear() in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, cin

I have a program here which will take float inputs, show it as an array and then we add more value to that array and show it again.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Add_to_Array(float*& a, int& n, float x){
 int m = n + 1;
 float* anew = (float*)realloc(a, m * sizeof(float));
 if(anew != NULL){
 anew[n] = x; n++;
 a = anew;
 }
}

void ArrayInput(float*& a, int &n){
 float x;
 a= NULL; n = 0;
 while(cin >> x)
 Add_to_Array(a, n, x);

 cin.clear();
}

void ArrayOutput(float a[], int n){
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 cout << a[i] << " ";
}

void Add_more_to_Array(float*& a, int &n){
 float x;
 while(cin >> x)
 Add_to_Array(a, n, x);
}

int main(){
 float* B; int nB;

 cout << "Type your input: " << endl;
 ArrayInput(B, nB);
 ArrayOutput(B, nB);

 cout << endl << "Add more to the array: " << endl;
 Add_more_to_Array(B, nB);
 cout << "New array: " << endl;
 ArrayOutput(B, nB);

 if(B != NULL)
 delete[] B;

 return 0;
}
```

If i end the input process `while(cin >> x)` of the  `ArrayInput` function by pressing "." on keyboard and then hit enter, the program will run perfectly without any errors.

However, if i, instead, end the input process `while(cin >> x)` of the  `ArrayInput` function by press something else on keyboard (such as "a", "," or "/",...), the program will pass the `Add_more_to_Array` function (it doesn't let me type my input) and output the same array. It seems to me that `while(cin >> x)` of the  `Add_more_to_Array` doesn't work in this situation.

Why does it work when i press "." and does not work when i press others? Is it because `cin.clear()` cannot clear anything more than "." or is it something in my code that cause the problem ? How can i fix it so when i press "s" to end the input process `while(cin >> x)` of the `ArrayInput` function the program still works ?

Comment: [std::istream::clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) doesn't clear anything from input buffer. It does clear the error state of an input stream. If you want to skip (wrong) input from input stream, please, have a look at [std::istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: I see `realloc` and `delete`, but I see no `new` or `malloc` in the code. I have a really bad feeling that you're walking into a trap. You can't `realloc` memory that you didn't  allocate in the first place. You can't `realloc` storage that you allocated with `new[]`. You cannot `delete[]` storage that you didn't allocate with `new[]`. It looks like you want to use `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`, but since this is C++, you probably really want to use `std::vector`.